# How do I get http request header fields server side in a Meteor.js app?

Tags: meteor

How do I get the http request header fields server side in a Meteor.js app?

For example in PHP one could use one of the following to determine what host or domain the request was on.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

I know on the client side I can get that from

```
document.domain
```

and then I could pass it to the server.

But is there an easier way to get at least the HOST (something.domain.com) that the client made the request on?

Comment: trying to understand why you need to do this, are you trying to make a virtual host aware meteor app?

Comment: Sort of.  More just musing on various multi-tenancy strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Meteor 0.7 you have to call on the server side

```
this.connection.httpHeaders
```

source http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/HTTP_Headers

Answer (score 2):

Your timing is great, I just wrote the following package a few days ago.

https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/headers

Use like this:

`js
var host = headers.get('host');`

Though if you're only after the host, and you can get it from one of the other solutions provided here, they're preferable.  The headers unfortunately have to make a round trip to the server and back, and the package is intended to get headers that aren't accessible any other way.

Comment: Good package.  I got it to work client side but server side calls returned undefined for 'host'

Comment: Oops, this is very old, but for the sake of clarity, this was fixed soon after your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl();
```

From the docs:

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl

Comment: I should have tried this.  It does return http://localhost:3000/ for which I could extract the host.